# ODE direction field doesn’t match solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

For the ODE $y’=\sqrt y$ and the initial condition $y(0)=0$ the solution is $y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$. This doesn’t match the direction field for the ODE. I wondered why this was happening here? I feel I am missing/overlooking something very basic

Comment: All functions $y(x)=\frac14\max(0,x-a)^2$ with $a\ge 0$ are solutions to your IVP.

Comment: Great! This really clears it up thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I have a plot of the slope field and of $y(x) = \frac14x^2$.

> [image]

We see that the right half fits the slope field perfectly, but the left half doesn't. So clearly something is wrong with the left half.

Not really. Or, it depends. Note that $\frac14x^2$ perfectly fulfills $(y')^2 = y$. So one could say that the non-fit is a result of choosing the "wrong sign" of the square root to the left of the $x$-intersection.

But also note that $y(x) = 0$ is a perfectly valid solution to your differential equation. And for any $a\in \Bbb R$, setting $y(x) = 0$ for $x\leq a$ and $y(x) = \frac14(x-a)^2$ for $x>a$, is also a valid solution.

So with your initial condition, and with the original differential equation $y' = \sqrt y$, all we can really say is that $a\geq 0$, possibly "$a = \infty$" (i.e. $y(x) = 0$ everywhere). With an initial condition like $y(1) = \frac14$, on the other hand, we fix $a = 0$.

Comment: A brilliant answer - thank you for being so thorough

Answer (score 3):

On solving the differential equation by variable separable method, we get$$\int\frac{y'}{\sqrt y}=\int dx\implies x-2\sqrt y=C$$The initial condition gives $C=0$. Note that in the solution $x=2\sqrt y$, both $x,y\ge0$. But when you square it to obtain $y=x^2/4$, it becomes defined for negative $x$. The curve over $x<0$ does not actually satisfy the ODE:$$y=x^2/4,x<0\implies \sqrt y=|x/2|=-x/2$$ giving $y'=-\sqrt y$ which is not the original ODE. You are probably seeing the mismatch between direction field and the curve tangents only over $x<0$ (look at the graph).

[image: Graph]

Comment: This makes sense! Is it related to uniqueness of solutions at all?

Comment: @MarinaCalder It is related to the fact that when you square an equation you introduce extraneous roots. I don't think it has to do with uniqueness of solution.

Comment: @MarinaCalder This particular IVP does NOT enjoy uniqueness.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You are not allowed to use the method of Separation of Variables for $y'=f(x)g(y)$, with $y(x_0)=y_0$, if $g(y_0)=0$, as in the OP.

Comment: Yes sorry- I meant the whole idea of uniqueness  - in this case definitely not unique!

Answer (score 0):

This IVP
$$
y'=\sqrt{y}, \quad y(0)=0
$$
does not enjoy uniqueness. (This is because the flux $\sqrt{y}$ is not sufficiently smooth.)

It possesses infinitely many solutions:
$$
y_c(x)=\max\left\{0,\frac{1}{4}(x-c)^2\right\}, \quad c \ge 0.
$$

Comment: This order of max and square is wrong, essentially the max has no effect, for $x<c$ this is not a solution.